# Dynamic pointer assignment c++

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, memory-address

2.
Given the definitions,

```
int *p1, *p2;
p1 = new int;
p2 = new int;
```

What is the difference between the following two assignments.

```
a) p1 = p2;
b) *p1 = *p2
```

Comment: You should tag it with the relevant language. But anyway, the first assignment is making the pointers equal (leaking some memory by the way..). The second - the values the pointers pointing to. I think it's pretty obvious..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) you are assigning the p2 (which is an address) to p1.So when you dereference the p1 you will get the value same as *p2. If you change the *p2 than *p1 will also change.So basically, in this type of assignment p1 and p2 both are referring to the same address location.This will produce the memory leak though since address assigned to p1 is not referenced anymore.

b) In this case value in the *p2 is assigned to *p1. But they are still pointing to different address location. If you change the value of *p2 after the assignment it will not change the *p1.

Comment: what type of values are inside the dereferenced p1 and p2 when testing I'm getting p1 is 0137C330
p2 is 0137C330
*p1 is -842150451
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Are you asking data type? You can print out the value and check it.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to mention language, but I guess you meant C or C++.

a) Simple address asigment. `p1` is going to be pointer to `p2`. So you end up with two pointers pointing towards one instance of int. That means, you loose pointer to p1 by overwriting it, but intance of it will stay in memory *unfreed* and you won't be able to free it or even access it! (If you didn't copy `p1` somewhere else ... ) Use valgrind to see that. However, when you call `delete p1`, you free even int, that is pointed by `p2`. Any usage of `p2` will probably end up with segmentation fault.

b) You are assigning value of p2, to p1, whic means, that you end up with two dynamically allocated pointers, both with value of p2. But they will be two differenc independent instances of int! So if you `delete p1`, `p2` will still be accessible.

Comment: Started to write a comment to the accepted answer about the memory leak, then read yours ... so have an upvote too! :)